# Why the following code is having deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

Can anyone please tell me why this code is suffering from deadlock?

```
public class BrokenOrderingReentredLock implements Runnable {

    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BrokenOrderingReentredLock runnable = new BrokenOrderingReentredLock();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable, "thread1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnable, "thread2");
        thread1.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        thread2.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            synchronized (lock1) {
                System.out.println(threadName + " has lock1");
                synchronized (lock2) {
                    System.out.println(threadName + " has lock2");
                        System.out.println(threadName + " reenters lock1");
                        lock1.wait();
                        lock2.wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } }
```

Comment: What do you see when you take a stack trace?  It should show you the deadlock.

Answer (score 7):

`Thread1` starts and gets `lock1` and `lock2`. `Thread1` releases `lock1` (with `lock1.wait()`).

`Thread2` starts and gets `lock1` then waits for `lock2` forever. `Thread1` is waiting to be notified, but will never be.

***DEADLOCK!***

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that thread1 gets a lock on lock1 and then a lock on lock2. Thread1 then calls lock1.wait which releases the lock on lock1 and makes thread1 wait there until someone calls notify (which never happens).

Thread2 comes along and gets a lock on lock1. It is then blocked from getting a lock on lock2 because thread1 still has the lock.

If you put a message between lock1.wait and lock2.wait, you'll see that neither thread ever gets that far so the lock on lock2 can never be released.